# Scala - Transform a Iterator into a Map

Tags: scala

How to get from an Iterator like this

`val it = Iterator("one","two","three","four","five")`

a map like

`Map(four -> 4, three -> 5, two -> 3, five -> 4, one -> 3)`

```
 var m = Map[String, Int]()
      while (it.hasNext) {
        val cell = it.next()
        m += (cell -> cell.length())
      }
```

this is a solution using `var` but I'd like to use just Immutable and `val` variable.

If I use the `for yield` statement the returning object would be a `Iterator[Map]` and I do not want that:

```
val m = for(i<- it if it.hasNext) yield Map(i->i.length())
```

Comment: Your `for` version is very odd. You don't need the `if` - the `for` already handles that, and you `yield` a separate `Map` for each entry, instead ot just the tuple. `{for (i <- it) yield (i -> i.length)}.toMap` would do it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can just use map:

```
val m = it.map(c => c -> c.length).toMap
```